# Magento 2 - PayPal Express - Charge shipping after an order was placed

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, paypal-express

Magento/2.3 (Community)

We have a client that charges it's customers for shipping after an order was placed. They have no issue charging if the payment method was Authorize.net - they're able to go in and re-charge the customer.

With PayPal Express however this doesn't seem possible. I've already looked at "Sale" and "Order" options for the PayPal Express settings, but editing an order in M2 admin doesn't allow me rebill the user's PayPal.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort of do it

Payment Action

Order

The amount of the order is neither captured nor authorized in the customer’s balance, bank account, or credit card at PayPal. The Order payment action represents an agreement between the PayPal payment system and the merchant, which enables the merchant to capture one or more amounts up to the “ordered” total from the customer’s buyer account, over a period of up to 29 days. After the funds are “ordered,” the merchant can capture them at any time during the following 29-day period. Capturing of the order amount can be done only from the Magento Admin by creating one or more invoices.

So basically create an order for the fullest amount and then capture twice, one for order and second later (possibly for less) once true postage is known

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just to add on to this a little bit, the client needs to fill in a specific shipping amount. They only provide "free shipping" then using a 3rd party shipping service they get a value then want to charge a custom amount more on top for the shipping. I tried the "Order" option and editing the shipping options just lets me choose a new shipping option...

Comment: You are going to struggle to get that with a lot of payment providers and they want ecommerce stores to be upfront with actual cost and will only let you charge less

Comment: Its going to be a difficult one to push but your client would be better suited to invest time trying to return accurate shipping rates and charge the right amount https://webshopapps.com/uk/magento-2-extensions/wsa-standalone/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html or a service like shipperhq

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful replies. I've advised the client as such.